# AWS EFS set default file permissions (ACL alternative)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, acl, amazon-efs

Related to this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=798230

This can easily be solved by using ACL permissions, but according to the above thread, it's not supported yet.

I have an EFS that is used by 2 separate processes on AWS linux EC2 instances. Basically one writes files to it and the other reads and deletes them. User "A" in group "G" writes the files, and user "B" also in group "G" reads/deletes the files.

How do I setup permissions so that new files by default have group rw permissions and are owned by group "G"? I could set the umask for the users to 002, but I only want the rw permissions to apply to the EFS mount, not the entire filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, even I am looking for a solution wherein we would like every new file to be created with RW group permissions so that other users in that directory could edit those too

Comment: @NitinG What I ended up doing is I automatically create a custom group "efs-user" and appended it to the ec2-user on any EC2 instance that connects to EFS. I used setgid on the EFS directory with rw perms so that everything within the EFS dir inherits the efs-user group. Append the efs-user group to any other users that require rw perms to EFS.

Comment: Hey Matt ... thanks for the update but I believe that with the setgid new files only inherit the parent directory group, not the permissions of the group on the parent directory. Can you please elaborate? looks intesresting

Comment: @NitinG The permissions of the group will also be inherited. So if you do something like `sudo chgrp efs-user dir/ && sudo chmod g+rws dir/` then creating a file in dir/ as a non-root user that belongs to the efs-user group will have the rw group permissions. Probably something like `-rw-rw---- root efs-user file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported yet. There is no update from AWS if what alternative could we do.